# separate threads for data acquisition and plotting

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I have a program written in C and running on Linux which acquires streaming data from a serial port device every 16 or so ms. This is a time critical piece of code that works fine. Another piece of code plots this data, also in real time, but its timely execution is less important to me than the data acquisition part. That is, I don't want to wait until all the plotting and drawing functions have finished before polling the serial port again. So I was thinking of having a separate thread do the plotting part of the application, or perhaps have the data acquisition part be the separate thread. I really have next to no experience when it comes to low-level programming, so could someone point me in the right direction? The pseudo-code with which I am working looks something like this:

```
int xyz; // global variable

int main() {

do_some_preliminary_stuff();

while 1 {
   poll_serial_port_and_fill_xyz_with_new_position_and_repeat();
}

while 1 {
   plot_xyz();
}

return 0;
}
```

Obviously as written, the code will be stuck in the first while loop, so yeah, threads?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, that is the way to go. Have non-main thread be the data acquisition thread, which posts the buffered response to the main/UI thread which does the plotting. Main thread should consume this data for plotting.

Answer (score 1):

Take care! Can your plotting routine keep up, on average, with the rate at which your data arrives on the serial port? If not, what should happen to xyz? Should un-plotted values be overwritten, or something else? If you can't keep up, this question needs to be answered first.

If you can keep up on average, then as you say you have little experience in low-level (i.e. threaded) programming, you might consider using two processes connected by a shell pipe:

```
poll_for_serial_data | plot_data
```

The first process is your while loop, writing the polled data to stdout in some convenient format. The second process reads dat from stdin and plots it. This achieves the same end as the multithreaded approach, but is simpler and easier to write as the OS handles the synchronisation and protection problems for you. And on Linux it's pretty efficient.

If this isn't performant enough for you, it could still act as a model for a multithreaded version.

Comment: As far as preliminary testing went, the plotting routines could in fact keep up with the data acq part. But if they couldn't , I wouldn't care too much if un-plotted samples were overwritten...

Comment: In that case, it is MUCH easier to use two processes rather than threads

Comment: I would do it at the shell level. Write one program which reads data from the serial port, and writes it to stout: preferably in text format, broken in to lines of X,Y,Z sets. Test it. Then write a second program that reads lines of data from stdin and plots them. You can test that one from a text file. Then put them together using a shell pipeline. Put a third tee(1) process in between the two and you can log data to file as well.